# bootstrap popover with jQuery rating(not showing up in popover....)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, yii, popover

I am using bootstrap popover with this Jquery's rating.
http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/
Right now the rating is not showing up in the popover(showing up as radio buttons), I realized that is because I need to load the rating again, so I tried the following code, still not working...

Any ideas?

```
 <script>
    $(function(){
    $('.review').popover({ 
    placement: 'in right',
    html: true,
    title: 'Reviews',
    content: $('.review-content').html()
    }).click(function(id,data){
    ("input").rating({"readOnly":true}); 

    });

    });

    </script>
```

Here are some markups for .review and review-content

```
<a class="review" style="color:black; position:relative;" href="#">Review</a>

<div class="review-content" style="display:none;" >

<span id="avg1">

<span class="star-rating-control"><div class="rating-cancel" style="display: none;"><a title="Cancel Rating"></a></div><div class="star-rating rater-0 star-rating-applied star-rating-readonly star-rating-on" id="avg1_0"><a title="1">1</a></div><div class="star-rating rater-0 star-rating-applied star-rating-readonly star-rating-on" id="avg1_1"><a title="2">2</a></div><div class="star-rating rater-0 star-rating-applied star-rating-readonly star-rating-on" id="avg1_2"><a title="3">3</a></div><div class="star-rating rater-0 star-rating-applied star-rating-readonly star-rating-on" id="avg1_3"><a title="4">4</a></div><div class="star-rating rater-0 star-rating-applied star-rating-readonly star-rating-on" id="avg1_4"><a title="5">5</a></div></span><input type="radio" name="avg1" value="1" id="avg1_0" class="star-rating-applied star-rating-readonly" style="display: none;">
<input type="radio" name="avg1" value="2" id="avg1_1" class="star-rating-applied star-rating-readonly" style="display: none;">
<input type="radio" name="avg1" value="3" id="avg1_2" class="star-rating-applied star-rating-readonly" style="display: none;">
<input type="radio" name="avg1" value="4" id="avg1_3" class="star-rating-applied star-rating-readonly" style="display: none;">
<input type="radio" name="avg1" checked="checked" value="5" id="avg1_4" class="star-rating-applied star-rating-readonly" style="display: none;">
</span>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Does this work?

```
$(function(){
    $('.review').popover({ 
        placement: 'in right',
        html: true,
        title: 'Reviews',
        content: function(){
           return $('.review-content').html()
        }
    }).click(function(id,data){
        (".popover-content input").rating({"readOnly":true}); 
    });    
});
```

Comment: It's hard to say, because the popover doesn't support anything as its content except a string.  In short it doesn't look like you'll be able to embed a plugin into the popover with the hooks popover currently gives you.

Comment: Really? I didn't know that tho. OK i guess i have to use some other hover way to do this... thank you!